# Padding in WGSL memory layout

Tags: javascript, webgpu, wgsl

I'm trying to write a WGSL structs parser (sort of webgpu-utils thing). In order to better understand the memory layout, I'm using [wgsl offset computer](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html) as a helper.

Having the next struct:

```
struct A {
  a: array<vec3f, 3>,
  b: f32
};
```

The layout given by the mentioned tool looks like:
[image]

I'm struggling with the difference between the graphical representation and the `AInfo` object. In the graphics, it is clearly seen that each item in the `array<vec3f, 3>` has alignment padding of 4 bytes and the offsets for three items are 0, 16 and 32 respectively. On the other hand, in the `AInfo` object the offset of the array `a` is zero and the length is 48 bytes. Referencing to the graphics, I would expect the object representation to be sort of:

```js
const AInfo = {
  a: [
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 0, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 16, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 32, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
  ],
  b: {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 48, length: 1}
};
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost never want an array of vec3's in JavaScript. It's too small of a unit so if you do this `array<vec3, 10000>` to really don't want it to create 10000 `Float32Array` views. So, the offset computer, or rather the webgpu-utils it's based on, doesn't create individual views for elements of base types because that would waste so much memory and be so slow and wasteful as to be useless.

Imagine if `array<f32, 10>` made

```
[
   new Float32Array(ab, 0, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 4, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 8, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 12, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 16, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 20, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 24, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 28, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 32, 1),
   new Float32Array(ab, 36, 1),
]
```

Those views are proably 128-256 bytes each, maybe more. So you'd end up using multiple kilobytes of memory to represent 10 f32s.

See: https://github.com/greggman/webgpu-utils/tree/dev#the-first-level-of-an-array-of-intrinsic-types-is-flattened

I can add an option to not flatten those but it's arguably bad practice. Technically a mat4x4f is an array of 4 vec4fs but I doubt anyone wants a mat4x4f representing by 4 views.

Comment: Actually, mat4x4 is simpler since it aligns perfectly with the 16 bytes layout. On the other hand, vec3f requires its own "row" in memory, such that each item must be padded. In order to pass data correctly, it is either I need to pad the data itself, which consumes additional 25% of memory in case of vec3f array, or have a better structure descriptor to allow to pad at runtime the delivered data...

Comment: padding vec3f array data is generally going to be way less memory than the code itself to handle passing individual parts of the array, 3 elements at a time.  In any case, I added an option to webgpu-utils so you can specify, for each type, whether you want arrays to be flattened or expanded into individual arrays. And I added a checkbox on the wgsl offset computer.

Comment: Please tell me if I get it right. If I'm loading a binary containing an array of vec3f to JS (unpadded), the byte size of it would be 3 items * 4 bytes each * array.length - let's call it a "source". In order to use according "set" for this data in the webgpu-utils, I will need to iterate over the source and pad it manually. Otherwise, I need to make sure the original data is already padded at export. Once I've padded the source, I need to adjust any manipulations I would like to make on it to take padding into account. In this case, I only pad once and save time/memory on each "set".

Comment: You should probably ask this on the [webgpu-utils discussions site](https://github.com/greggman/webgpu-utils/discussions) Whether you use webgpu-utils set or not, one way or another you're going to have to convert the unpadded data to padded data. You can also just get the `Float32Array` view from webgpu-utils results, rather than calling set. See `projectionMatrix` example in the [readme](https://github.com/greggman/webgpu-utils#easily-set-uniforms-based-on-your-wgsl-structstypes)